# How to install cleos?

Tags: cleos

I've installed EOSIO.cdt from [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/EOSIO.cdt) . But I can't access cleos program and getting :

> Command 'cleos' not found, did you mean   command 'cleo' from deb
> cleo Try: sudo apt install

Firstly I installed Debian Package then build from scratch but in all cases I'm getting that command not found.
Also my folder /usr/local/eosio.cdt/include even doesn't contains any cleos dir or files.

Comment: complete the install step after finishing building

Comment: Can you share how are you trying to use the cleos command?

Comment: I've completed building by installing: sudo ./install.sh/.

Comment: Any cleos command returns that. For example: $cleos wallet create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Debian, you can install using the install method provided in the docs:

```
wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/download/v1.7.0/eosio_1.7.0-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./eosio_1.7.0-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb

// test
nodeos -v
// v1.7.0
```

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/setting-up-your-environment

---

As others have previously mentioned, nodeos, cleos, and keosd are all installed with eos.  If you have an issue with your install, please share your OS information.

Answer (score 0):

Cleos isn't installed with the Eosio.cdt. You need to install [Eos](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos), it contains and will install [Keosd](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.2.0/docs/keosd-overview) and [Cleos](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.2.0/docs/cleos-overview), too. There's currently no (easy) way to build and install Keosd and Cleos without building Eos itself.

If you don't want to go through the full Eos-installation Eos-Canada has built a lightwheight alternative named [Eosc](https://github.com/eoscanada/eosc).